# Whats the most effective way to store a chemical formula?

Tags: list, collections, hashset

I currently have have a HashSet of `NElement` objects. Each `NElement` object has a unique `Element` field, and an integer n.

Here are 2 operations I need to do with the data:

1. Iterate over all the values in collection.
2. With `Element e`, search the collection for an instance of `NElement` that has `e` and process it.

Here's an example of #2:

```
public void Add(NElement ne) {
    foreach(NElement ne2 in elements) { //elements is the HashSet
        if(ne2.element == ne.element) {
            ne2.Number += ne.Number; //Number is the integer
            return;
        }
    }
    elements.Add(ne);
}
```

I think there is a better way to accomplish this using a collection other than a List or Set. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are there a limited number of elements that you will be working with?  Or would you need to support the full periodic table?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using a Map?

Comment: @JayDM I'm representing a molecular formula, so its a minimum of nothing and maximum of the largest possible molecule. I'm not adding elements that aren't present in the formula.

Comment: @JordanKaye I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it. Mind showing an example setup for a Map that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution would be a bit of a different design. A molecular formula consists of a bunch of elements along with how many of those elements there are. So a possible solution is to have a `MolecularFormula` class that wraps this information, which is based in a 
`Map<Element, int>`.

A possible example:

```
public class MolecularFormula
{
    private Map<Element, int> elements = new HashMap<Element, int>();

    //... Constructors etc
    //A list to iterate through all values
    public List<NElement> getElements()
    {
        List<NElement> retList = new ArrayList<NElement>();
        foreach(Element e : elements)
        {
            retList.put(new NElement(e, elements.get(e));
        }
        return retList;
    }

    //To add something
    public void add(Element e, int num)
    {
        if(elements.containsKey(e))
        {
            int newNum = elements.get(e) + num;
            elements.remove(e);
            elements.put(e, newNum);
        }
        else
        {
            elements.put(e, num);
        }
    }
}
```

This is hastily thrown together and not very efficient at all, but it should give you an idea of a possible option.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I knew a Map or something similar would be better, but didn't know the right key-value combination. This clarified it a lot.

Comment: When thinking about Map, always try to think about what you have that's unique - the unique type will always be your key!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [SMARTS](http://www.daylight.com/dayhtml_tutorials/languages/smarts/index.html), [SMILES](http://www.daylight.com/dayhtml/doc/theory/theory.smiles.html), [InChi](http://www.iupac.org/home/publications/e-resources/inchi.html) or [ASL](http://www.schrodinger.com/kb/1289). The first two are open source, I believe. InChi is maintained by the IUPAC, and is nicely hashable for database use. ASL is proprietary to [Schrödinger, Inc](http://www.schrodinger.com/), though if you are already using Schrödinger software, I'd recommend using their Python API directly.

Using any of these tools, you could find functional groups (or atoms) described by a specific SMARTS/SMILES/ASL string within a molecule described by SMARTS/SMILES/ASL.

Comment: Yes, I'm using SMILES for some of the functionality. However, I am parsing basic chemical formulas. Also, I need a way to represent molecules in memory, instead of a string.

Comment: I suppose my answer was for a more general problem which includes structure, rather than only formula. Jordan Kaye's answer indeed makes more sense for this issue.